# Chips - Materialize CSS

Tags: jquery, materialize

How to get the chip image src upon deleting a chip in materiliaze css?

```
$('.chips').on('chip.delete', function(e, chip){
              var data = $('e.target.id').material_chip('data');
              var url = data[0].image;
 });
```

i have done this but not able to get the image url. how to do it?

Comment: `console.log(e.target)` and see what you get.

Comment: yeah I did that but nothing displayed.

Comment: You put that in your event handler and it didn't put anything in the console?  Not even a blank string or anything?

Comment: nothing displayed in the console when i hit the delete chip event

Comment: That would suggest then that the event handler is not being invoked.  Make sure you have no console errors.  You could try putting `debugger;` in there and have the developer tools open and try to run it.  If your browser doesn't pause on the command, that logic is not being invoked.

Comment: is my syntax correct?

Comment: Well other than the selector on your data lookup being e.target.id in a string, which isn't a valid selector.  But if you put the console.log or debugger; before that it wouldn't hit an error with that before it executed.  But I'm also not an expert with materialize so I'm just trying to confirm that the event handler is processing at all at this point.

Comment: actually when i invoke the delete chip event and console anything at random, nothing gets displayed